# Ayuda con el funcionamiento correcto de html2pdf en php

Tags: php, html2pdf

Necesito generar un pdf con información personal de un usuario (datos personales), pero necesito un botón que inicie la descarga en la misma pantalla, no requiero abrir ningún otra ventana para visualizarlo. Entonces.

Ya tengo todo el HTML con algo más o menos así:

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST['pdf])){
   $pdf = new pdfcontroller();
   $pdf->generarPdf();
 ?>
<html>

<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
  {aqui los datos del usuario}

  <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="pdf" value="Descargar pdf">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Y esta es mi clase del controlador con la librería importada correctamente:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../libs/html2pdf/vendor/autoload.php');
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;

    class pdfcontroller{


        public function generarPdf(){

        }
    }
```

Ahora bien, ya comprendí que para esta librería necesito maquetar el HTML y enviar todos los parámetros a mi controlador para poder generar el pdf y bueno, eso sin falla lo puedo resolver, pero me apura el asunto ese de que el controlador me pueda regresar un objeto en pdf o en dado caso iniciarlizar la descarga del archivo.

Gracias infinitas por su ayuda, quedo totalmente agradecido desde ya.

Comment: ¿Necesitas visualizar el PDF en la misma ventana o bien necesitas solo descargar el archivo PDF en esa ventana?

Comment: Descargarlo en esa misma ventana.

Comment: Te dejo una respuesta para solucionar el problema en unos segundos.

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta ya que la anterior no me copio el código completo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu `function` `generarPDF()` deberia verse asi:

```
public function generarPDF()
{
    // Logic

    if($this->html2pdf->create('save')) 
    {
        $this->downloadPDF(); // Acá es donde se genera la descarga del PDF
    }
}

public function downloadPDF()
{
    if(is_dir("./tu-ruta"))
    {
        $route = base_url("tu-ruta/" . "cualquier-cosa" . ".pdf");
        $filename = "name-file" . ".pdf";

        if(file_exists("././tu-ruta/" . $filename))
        {
            header("Cache-Control: public"); 
            header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
            header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' .basename($route)); 
            header("Content-Type: application/pdf"); 
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
            readfile($route);
        }
    }
}
```

Es importante que en la `function` `downloadPDF` se respeten los / tal cual los coloque, de lo contrario no funcionara.

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias me sirvió muchísimo para comprender el funcionamiento (la lógica)

Answer (score 0):

Cuando en el controlador llegues a la parte de guardar el archivo has esto:

```
$fichero = "fichero.pdf";
$html2pdf->output($fichero);

return $fichero; // "fichero.pdf"
```

Ya luego en tu HTML el $pdf->generarPdf(); te devolvera el nombre del fichero, lo que tienes que hacer es poner un enlace con la ruta donde se guarden tus ficheros pdfs

```
echo "<a class='btn btn-primary' download target="_blank" href='AQUI_LA_RUTA/$fichero'></a>";
```

Y si, primero tendrias que guardar el fichero localmente para luego descargarlo con un enlace.

Comment: No, no quiero una vista previa, necesito la descarga automática del archivo... entonces ¿Para hacer esto, primero necesito guardarlo localmente?.. :O

Comment: @NeftaliAcosta revisa la respuesta que te deje.

Comment: Te actualizo la respuesta.